# Using SUM in my SELCET and then use it my WHERE statement

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to sort the list I have.

I do a SUM and GROUP BY to get all the users.

But when I have this row. Then it doesn't work anymore.
"HAVING ua.hands_tongits >= cp.approved_limit AND"

I narrowed it down to that its this "ua.hands_tongits" I guess its because its a part of the SUM.
If I put a number insted ua.hands_tongits then it works.

Any idea why I can't use the SUM in my WHERE?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NBo7.png)

I expect to get a list of all the players that is not locked out from the web page.
"WHERE um.meta_key = 'baba_user_locked' AND um.meta_value = 'yes'"

And SUM all the activity they been doing.

And group so I just get one user and its activity in every record.

But I want to sort so I only give me the users that has been collecting enought points.
"HAVING ua.hands_tongits >= cp.approved_limit AND"

This is my full SQL code.

```
SELECT cp.*, c.cashback_profile_id, u.*, wu.*, ua.date_, ua.player_id, SUM(ua.hands_tongits) AS hands_tongits, SUM(ua.hands_pusoy) AS hands_pusoy, SUM(ua.hands_poker) AS hands_poker, SUM(ua.hands_lucky9) AS hands_lucky9, SUM(ua.hands_pusoy_dos) AS hands_pusoy_dos, SUM(ua.hands_colorgame) AS hands_colorgame, SUM(ua.total_hands) AS total_hands 
FROM tongiaya_ligaya.users_activity ua
INNER JOIN tongiaya_twp.twp_users wu ON wu.user_nicename = ua.player_id
INNER JOIN tongiaya_ligaya.users u ON u.user_nicename = ua.player_id 
INNER JOIN tongiaya_ligaya.club c ON c.club_id = u.club_id
INNER JOIN tongiaya_ligaya.cashback_profile cp ON cp.profile_id = c.cashback_profile_id
WHERE 
ua.date_ >= '%ResultedDate%' AND 
HAVING ua.hands_tongits >= cp.approved_limit AND
ua.player_id NOT IN 
    (
    SELECT um.user_id
    FROM tongiaya_twp.twp_usermeta AS um
    WHERE um.meta_key = 'baba_user_locked' AND  um.meta_value = 'yes'
    )
GROUP BY ua.player_id
ORDER BY u.tree_level DESC;
```

Comment: please edit your question to include your select, as text, not image

Comment: WHERE should only refer to columns from the source rows, *before* aggregation by GROUP BY.

Comment: The query shown on the screenshot is incorrect absolutely. Read about incomplete GROUP BY. Enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY then fix the query.